# Finding whether a set and an array have any strings in common

Tags: java

I have the following code.  It looks through an array, called `items`, and checks to see if there are any items in that array that also exist in a certain set of strings, called `stringSet`.

```
    Set<String> stringSet = new HashSet<>();
    stringSet.add("A");
    stringSet.add("B");
    stringSet.add("C");

    String[] items = new String[2];
    items[0] = "A";
    items[1] = "D";

    boolean hasValue = false;

    for (String item : items) {
        if (stringSet.contains(item)) {
            hasValue = true;
        }
    }
    System.err.println(hasValue);
```

Is there any way to avoid using a `for each` loop to achieve same result in Java 8, like with a `stream`, a `map`, etc.?

Comment: Since this is a question about how to code something more than a review of a complete class/method, it might be better suited to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the following stream in place of for-loop

```
Arrays.stream(items)
            .anyMatch(stringSet::contains);
```

What you are trying to do is loop through the items, and any time the item is contained in the string set u want to return true. 
anyMatch function breaks as soon as any of the items returns true

Comment: Please add why this alternative is better than the `for`-loop solution. Code dumps ('try this:') are not allowed as answers here.

Comment: @Coal_ I don't think that, in this case, justification for the stream solution is required, since the question explicitly asked for a solution that avoids a `for` loop, so it was basically asking for a code dump.

Comment: If OP's *only* concern was getting rid of the `for`-loop, the question is definitely too narrow for Code Review SE. Alas, this answer is here now, and it should be edited to comply to the [guidelines for writing a good answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Coal_ I have added the explaination, I don't know what else can i add in it, its just too straight forward. Any suggestion would be welcome

Comment: I agree this is a weird position you're in, and appreciate your efforts nevertheless. I think this is good enough.

Answer (score 3):

Your `for` loop iterates over the whole array even after it encounters a `String` that is contained in `stringSet`. This is not necessary – it is sufficient to terminate the loop once an array element is found to be contained in `stringSet`, which is also known as short-circuiting. The solution suggested by vishva is short-circuiting, as stated in its [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#anyMatch(java.util.function.Predicate)).

Comment: so in my for-each-loop example, i can achieve short-circuiting using a `break` keyword once `hasValue` is true right?

Comment: @hades Exactly. A possibility without `break` would be to replace the for-each loop with a plain `for` loop with an explicit termination condition and increment statement, and include the value of `hasValue` in the termination condition. Whether this is more readable than terminating the loop from within using `break` is probably subjective. I think using `break` here would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Another straightforward option is to convert the array to a `Set` and use set operations:

```
Set<String> stringSet = new HashSet<>();
stringSet.add("A");
stringSet.add("B");
stringSet.add("C");

String[] items = new String[2];
items[0] = "A";
items[1] = "D";

Set<String> itemsSet = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(items));
// itemSet becoming the intersection of both sets
itemsSet.retainAll(stringSet);

boolean hasValue = !itemsSet.isEmpty();
```

Since this solution will find all matches, it will have higher complexity than your original solution.